# Show that $f = 0$ almost everywhere in $E$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Assume $E \subset \mathbb R^n$, $f: E\rightarrow \mathbb R_e $ is measurable on $E$, and $\int \limits_A f = 0$ for every
measurable set $A \subset E$. Show that $f = 0$ a.e.(almost everywhere) in $E$. Note that if $f = 0$ a.e. in $E$ then there is $Z\subset E$ where the property does not hold and $Z$ is Lebesgue measurable and $|Z|=0$. We are given that if $f:A\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is measurable on $A$ and $\int_A f=0$, then $f=0$ a.e. in $A$.

Here is my attempt at this problem. 
By the definition of a property holding almost everywhere we know that 
$$Z = \lbrace x\in E : f(x) \neq 0\rbrace = \lbrace x\in E : f(x) > 0\rbrace \cup \lbrace x\in E : f(x) < 0\rbrace$$
First show that $Z$ is measurable. Lets say that $Z_1 = \lbrace x\in E : f(x) > 0\rbrace$ and $Z_2 = \lbrace x\in E : f(x) < 0\rbrace$
Since $f$ is a measurable function, we know that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are measurable sets. $Z_1$ is measurable by the definition of being measurable ([Measurable Function Definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeasurableFunction.html)) and $Z_2$ is measurable by a thm that says if $f$ is a measurable function then $\lbrace x\in E : f(x) < a\rbrace$ is measurable for every $a\in \mathbb R$. The union of measurable sets is measurable so the set $Z$ is a measurable set.

Now show that $|Z|=0$. We are given that for each measurable set $A \in E$ that $\int \limits_A f = 0$. So say there are two measurable sets (**Can I say this or must I show this?**) $A\subset E$ and $B\subset E$ such that $f:A \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ and $f:B \rightarrow [-\infty, 0]$ and $A\cup B = E$. Another way to write it 
$$A = \lbrace x\in E : f(x)\geq 0\rbrace \text{ and } B = \lbrace x\in E : f(x)\leq 0\rbrace$$.
 This implies that $\int_A f = 0$ and $\int_B f = 0$ . Since $A$ and $B$ are measurable sets this implies that $f:A \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ and $f:B \rightarrow [-\infty, 0]$ are measurable functions (**See bottom for my explaination**).

Using the problem statement, we know that if $f:A\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is measurable on $A$ and $\int_A f=0$, then $f=0$ a.e. in $A$ which implies that $|Z_1| = 0$ .$f:A\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is measurable on $A$ and $\int_A f=0$ so $|Z_1| = 0$.

Now say $-f:B\rightarrow [0,\infty]$. We can use the problem statement to say if $-f:B\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is measurable on $B$ and $\int_B -f=0$, then $-f=0$ a.e. in $B$ which implies that $|Z_2| = 0$. 
$-f:B\rightarrow [0,\infty]$
is equivalent to $\lbrace x\in E : -f(x)\geq 0\rbrace$. Since 
$$\lbrace x\in E : -f(x)\geq 0\rbrace = \lbrace x\in E : f(x)\leq 0\rbrace$$
and $\lbrace x\in E : f(x)\leq 0\rbrace$ is measurable, this implies that $\lbrace x\in E : -f(x)\geq 0\rbrace$ is measurable hence $-f:B\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is a measurable function. Since $B$ is measurable we can use the problem statement to say that $\int_B -f = 0 \Rightarrow \int_B f = 0$. This shows that $-f=0 \Rightarrow f=0$ a.e. in $B$ which implies that $|Z_2| = 0$

So I showed that $|Z_1| = 0$ and $|Z_2| = 0$ which implies that $|Z| = 0$. Hence $f=0$ a.e. on E.

*$f:A \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is measurable since $\lbrace x\in A : f(x)\geq 0\rbrace$ either equals $A$ or the empty set. Since both are measurable it follows that $\lbrace x\in A : f(x)\geq 0\rbrace$ is measurable and that $f$ is a measurable function on $A$. The same argument hold for $B$.

Comment: Couldn't you simply say that $\mu(\{f>\frac1n\})=0$ and $\mu(\{-f>\frac1n\})=0$ and therefore $\mu(\{f\ne0\})=\mu(\bigcup_n \{f>\frac1n\}\cup\{-f>\frac1n\})=0$?

Comment: I am not familiar with the $\mu$ notation, what does it signify?

Comment: $\mu(E)$ is the measure of $E$, you denoted it by $\lvert E\rvert$.

Comment: Technically, yes. What you are saying is correct, but how could you show that without the fact that the integral over the region equals 0? Even with that I had trouble showing the measure of the second set of your union is 0 due to the negative.